# Kubernestes throwing 503 error after deployment, service and ingress deployment

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

Hi I have deployed deployment, services and ingress in kubernetes. whenever I try to access my host its throwing 503 error. Below is my deployment.yml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment 
metadata: #Dictionary
  name: vessel-assurance-deployment
  namespace: vesselassurance-dev
spec: # Dictionary
  replicas: 1
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      # maxUnavailable will set up how many pods we can add at a time
      maxUnavailable: 50%
      # maxSurge define how many pods can be unavailable during the rolling update
      maxSurge: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: vessel-assurance
  template:  
    metadata: # Dictionary
      name: vessel-assurance-pod
      labels: # Dictionary
        app: vessel-assurance  # Key value paids
    spec:
      containers: # List
        - name: vessel-assurance-container
          image: ghcr.io/myorg/myprod:latest
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports: 
            - containerPort: 8080
          resources:
            requests:
              memory: "64Mi"
              cpu: "50m"
            limits:
              memory: "128Mi"
              cpu: "100m"
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: githubpackagesecret
```

Below is my service.yml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: vessel-assurance-service #### Insert your application service name here ####
  namespace: vesselassurance-dev #### Insert your application's namespace. Omit this line to use default namespace. ####
  labels:
    app: vessel-assurance-app #### Insert your application service name here ####
spec:
  # Use one of ClusterIP, LoadBalancer or NodePort. See https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: vessel-assurance #### Insert your application deployment name here. This must match the deployment name specified in the deployment manifest ####
    instance: app
  ports:
    - port: 8080 #### Replace with appropriate port
      targetPort: 8080 #### Replace with the port name defined in deployment
```

Below is my ingress

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: vessel-assurance-ingress #### Insert your application service name here ####
  namespace: vesselassurance-dev #### Insert your application's namespace. Omit this line to use default namespace. ####
  labels:
    website: vessel-assurance-deployment #### Insert your application service name here ####
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 2000m
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: 'add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=2628000; includeSubDomains" always;'
spec:
  # Uses the NGINX ingress controller to direct traffic to the service
  ingressClassName: nginx
 
  rules:
    - host: myhost
      http:
        paths:
        - pathType: Prefix
          path: "/"
          backend:
            service:
              name: vessel-assurance-service
              port:
                number: 8080
        
 
  tls:
  - hosts:
    # Replace "application" with application name
    - vessel-assurance.dev.myorg.net
   
    secretName: tls-wildcard-myorg-digital-net
```

After deployment wheneverI tried to access my app I get 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable and below it shows nginx. I am not able to figure it out the issue. Can some pls help me to figure out the issue. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't provided additional information regarding the error such as pod, service, endpoint status, etc. Better to check following as a quick check.

1. You are having different hosts in `spec.rules.host` and `spec.tls.hosts`, but they need to be identical as per the docs: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#tls
2. Have you deployed the NGINX Ingress controller? Are the pods in that deployment running without errors?
3. According to the labels that you have added, it seems the service should be correctly mapped to the respective pod. But make sure that the endpoint in the service contains the IP of your pod correctly.

Comment: Thanks Sahan. I ran describe service and I see Endpoints: None. Is this causing the issue?

Comment: Yes, this should be the reason. I just noticed that your service has another selector label as `instance: app` which is not in the pod. Try removing `instance: app` label from selector in the service and see.